# Is Sugar a stimulatant or a weak sedative?

Tags: diet, sugar

Quite often, I have heard the remark that children become hyperactive when high amounts of sugar are consumed.

But common websites suggest that sugar is a sedative, and the hyperactivity in children is more likely caused by 'artificial dyes and preservatives'. (http://curezone.com/forums/am.asp?i=1444631)

So, is Sugar a stimulant (for adults and children) or is it a sedative? Is there any conclusive research to validate this theory?

Comment: Can you tell us which websites do claim this?

Comment: better ask at skeptics.SE

Comment: @edition Sorry, but this page is not a source to be trusted. As Jeremy already answered, this is pseudoscientific b*llsh*t.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, but you wanted a website :)

Answer (score 3):

The idea that 'dyes and preservatives' cause hyperactivity dates back to [this '76 paper](http://www.feingold.org/Research/PDFstudies/Feingold76.pdf) by one Dr. Feingold. Despite being [disproved neatly](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/353681) in 1978, it's still around.

As far as sugar goes, I recommend [this review paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8747098) covers both the arguments for and against sugar causing hyperactivity, as well as 12 double-blind placebo controlled studies showing sugar has no effect on children's actual behavior.

Comment: What about sedative effects? Is there a paper in that context? And what about adults?

Comment: I couldn't find anything testing specifically sedative effects. I don't see a plausible mechanism and 'no effect' means no effect, hyperactive or sedative. If you can think of a reason why something would be psychoactive only in adults, let me know, but I feel comfortable generalizing from children to adults here.

Comment: Could you provide a summary of these arguments? It's better to have the answer _here_ rather than on another site which is behind a paywall (not everyone has institutional subscriptions)